# Show Desktop button in VB.NET Windows Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

In my vb.net windows form application i want make a button that when a user cliked the button, the Desktop should be showed, (Show Desktop Button) .

Consider a form name as form1 and it got a button like "Show desktop", when user clicked, all the application should be minimized and it should show desktop, is there any Code for VB.NET Windows Form application.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

Although my proposed solution work, but I would recommend using **Code Gray's** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54916328/395500) below, as that's the right way to do it.

---

In C# it goes like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
class Program {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
    const int MIN_ALL = 419;
    const int MIN_ALL_UNDO = 416;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        IntPtr lHwnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);
        SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COMMAND, (IntPtr)MIN_ALL, IntPtr.Zero); 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COMMAND, (IntPtr)MIN_ALL_UNDO, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
}
```

I used an [online converter tool](http://converter.telerik.com/) to convert the above code, please verify if it works

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace ConsoleApplication1
    Class Program
        <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint := "FindWindow", SetLastError := True)> _
        Private Shared Function FindWindow(lpClassName As String, lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
        End Function
        <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint := "SendMessage", SetLastError := True)> _
        Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As Int32, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        End Function

        Const WM_COMMAND As Integer = &H111
        Const MIN_ALL As Integer = 419
        Const MIN_ALL_UNDO As Integer = 416

        Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
            Dim lHwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", Nothing)
            SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COMMAND, DirectCast(MIN_ALL, IntPtr), IntPtr.Zero)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
            SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COMMAND, DirectCast(MIN_ALL_UNDO, IntPtr), IntPtr.Zero)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this link. This contains the code to minimise all windows showing the desktop.
http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2109.htm

```
Public Sub ShowDesktop()
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, 0, 0)
keybd_event(77, 0, 0, 0)
keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
End Sub

Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, _
ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Private Const VK_LWIN = &H5B

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)         Handles Button1.Click
Call ShowDesktop()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions proposed in the existing answers are hacks that rely on undocumented aspects of Windows. They may work now, but they are subject to stop working at any time with a Windows update.

[Marshal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10361106) tries to find the actual "Show Desktop" button in the taskbar. One obvious issue is that the names and IDs of the windows are hard-coded, which means the code breaks if those ever change in the OS itself. These OS internals are not documented, not intended for programmatic manipulation by applications, and subject to change at any time. I also don't know what happens if the user modifies their OS settings to not show this button in the taskbar. Does the code continue to work? Are these messages still supported? I don't know. Do you?

[Harsh's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10361113) relies on synthesizing a press of the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> key combination, which is the keyboard shortcut for showing the desktop. This has all the standard problems of synthesizing keyboard input, with the added disadvantage that it uses the old, deprecated `keybd_event` function (`SendInput` is its replacement, which solves some of the problems with `keybd_input`, namely that there is no way to handle errors, but doesn't solve the larger problems with synthesized keyboard events.) This solution is less likely to break with a Windows update, since this keyboard shortcut is documented, but may have undesirable side effects and subtle issues interacting with other system functions and/or applications.

A better solution is to delegate to the COM component Shell32.dll, calling its documented [`ToggleDesktop` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/shell-toggledesktop), which does exactly what you want to do. From the MSDN documentation:

> This method has the same effect as the **Show Desktop** button on the taskbar. It either hides all open windows to show the desktop or it hides the desktop by showing all open windows. The `ToggleDesktop` method does not display a user interface, it just invokes the toggle action.

Since this is documented, it is much more likely to continue working as Windows is updated. Since it doesn't rely on hackery or synthesized events, it is less likely to cause subtle incompatibilities. It's also just plain *easier to use*.

Both C# and VB.NET make it easy to access COM libraries. In C#, calling the function is as simple as:

```
Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
shell.ToggleDesktop();
```

In VB.NET, that becomes (look ma, no semicolons):

```
Dim shell As Shell32.Shell = New Shell32.Shell()
shell.ToggleDesktop()
```

You may need to add a reference to "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation" (the Shell32.dll library), if one doesn't already exist in your project. This is a system DLL, so it's present on all systems.

The only requirement is that you invoke this function from a thread which is using a Single-Threaded Apartment (STA) model. In other words, it is not thread-safe and doesn't handle its own synchronization. That is not, however, a significant drawback, as all Windows Forms applications use an STA thread: it is the main thread, the one that handles the UI and pumps messages. UI threads are virtually always STA, and guaranteed to be so in WinForms. Just don't try and call this from a background/worker thread. Not that you would, since you should only try and show the desktop in response to a direct user interaction, which would be handled on the UI thread anyway.

Comment: Thanks so Much For This <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

`shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}` is indeed the best solution as it is the known documented CLSID from MSDN

Answer (score -2):

```
   Shell("cmd.exe /c %windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}", AppWinStyle.MinimizedNoFocus)
```

The best solution

Comment: Can you explain this solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.